# What do I need to learn in order to work with S-Functions in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I'm a little confused on how to use S-Functions in Simulink. I understand that I can write my code in C/C++ to 'build' a block that will interact with other elements in a Simulink project.

So, I started to write simple functions in C ([like to add 2 numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5o5R0VnptZw)) and then integrate it into Simulink using Legacy Code Tool. However, as I need a more complicated code to model a power electronics device, I'm reading more and I've seen [different structures](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/simulink/sfg/sfunc_c5.html#94774) of codes and I'm getting confused on which should I use and learn.

Any help would be truly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Start by reading the `Concepts` section of [Simulink Basics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/s-function-basics.html), then ask more specific questions when you start writing your code.

Comment: The comment above should say `S-Function Basic`, not `Simulink Basics`.